# multiple elements with ng-click within in md-list-item

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am newbie in web development and am still getting used to using the angular material directives.

I am trying to embed an `md-button` in the `md-list-item` directive and would like two separate `ng-click` actions on the item. One for the `md-list-item` in general and one for the `md-button` element embedded in to the `md-list-item` which would perform a different action.

What I am seeing right now is that on clicking the `md-button` both `ng-click` functions get executed.

Is there a better way of doing this. The reason I set the ng-click on md-list-item is to get the ripple and hover effect on the `md-list-item` element.

Here is my code snippet :

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-click="playSong(song)" flex ng-class="{'md-content-active' : playing === song.title}">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
        <h3>{{ song.title }}</h3>
        <h4>{{ song.album }}</h4>
        <p>{{ song.year }}</p>
    </div>
    <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-mini md-primary">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="assets/icons/playlist_add.svg" ng-click="addPlaylist(song)"" aria-label="add_playlist"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: try using `event.stopPropagation();` on the mdButton ng-click function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `md-secondary` class to your button:

```
<md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-secondary md-fab md-mini md-primary" ng-click="addPlaylist(song)">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="assets/icons/playlist_add.svg" aria-label="add_playlist"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Comment: Nope didnt help :S Still executing both functions

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: Oh got it. I moved the ng-click in to the md-button directive instead of the md-icon and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohnSmith If there is md-checkbox how is this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the the click event from propagating up the dom. Pass the $event into the function call for the deeper click event. See below:

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-click="playSong(song)" flex ng-class="{'md-content-active' : playing === song.title}">
<div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
    <h3>{{ song.title }}</h3>
    <h4>{{ song.album }}</h4>
    <p>{{ song.year }}</p>
</div>
<md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-mini md-primary">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="assets/icons/playlist_add.svg" ng-click="addPlaylist(song, $event)"" aria-label="add_playlist"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Then on the function itself:

```
$scope.addPlaylist = function(song, ev){ev.stopPropagation(); //rest of whatever this is supposed to do}
```